# Image optimizer Magento1.9.3.2

Tags: magento-1.9, extensions, image, optimization, magento-1.9.3.2

I am using Apptrian Image Optimizer. The extension for Magento1. I have given all the necessary permission to the files which are responsible for optimizing. Still, I am getting the following error when turn on the error logs:-

```
DEBUG (7): optipng is not executable.
```

Please let me know if I have to install the utilities on the server as well. Or is there any way out to get this done, by not using the `exe` files

> P.S:- I have also checked the files and they are not corrupted

Comment: https://marketplace.magento.com/scommerce-scommerce-optimizeimages.html - This module doesn't use any utility installed on your server or required any special permission, may be worth a try.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Check if the optipng binary is available:

`which optipng`

If it was found, make sure it has the correct access permissions:

`chmod +x PATH_FROM_optipng`

Comment: The extension provides a lib folder which has an exe and a text file which I assume will be the bin file you are referring to.

Comment: If you are running Magento on a Linux Server, you won't be able to run an .exe file.

Comment: The optipng is a common tool, also available for linux. #

Comment: If you are running Magento on a Linux Server, you won't be able to run an .exe file
>> Let me check both. Thanks